# Control.Applicative lifting on n-lists

Tags: haskell

I am quite new to Haskell and would like to know how to achieve the following output without using a fixed comprehension list (or indeed an applicative functor like liftA) i.e.

```
> [ [x+y+z] | x <- [1,11], y <- [1,11], z <- [1,11]]
> [[3],[13],[13],[23],[13],[23],[23],[33]]
```

The above code example only processes 3 lists e.g. xyz.  How can I achieve the same thing using n lists e.g. e.g. [[1,11]] or [[1,11],[1,11],[1,11],[1,11],[1,11]] ?

PS - I looked at using a control Applicative functor liftA but its limited to liftA3 e.g.

```
 λ> :m + Control.Applicative
 λ> let combine = liftA2 (,)
 λ> combine "ab" "cd"
 [('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','c'),('b','d')]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using *n* copies of the same list `[1,11]` you can use `replicateM`:

```
import Control.Monad

ghci> replicateM 3 [1,11]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,11],[1,11,1],[1,11,11],[11,1,1],[11,1,11],[11,11,1],[11,11,11]]

ghci> map sum (replicateM 3 [1,11])
[3,13,13,23,13,23,23,33]
```

In general, you can use `sequence` to perform a multi-list cartesian product:

```
ghci> sequence [ [1,11], [2,22], [3,33] ]
[[1,2,3],[1,2,33],[1,22,3],[1,22,33],[11,2,3],[11,2,33],[11,22,3],[11,22,33]]
```

Comment: yes thanks - looking for ... nub $ map sum $ sequence [ [1,11], [1,11] ] etc. as its not monadic ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the flexibility of handling inputs *that aren't just lists of `[1,11]`*:

```
λ> import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
λ> let sumsOfCombinations xs = (:[]) . sum <$> foldr (liftA2 (:)) [[]] xs
```

You can pass it any list of list of numbers:

```
λ>  sumsOfCombinations' [[0,100],[-1,0,1],[0,1000]]
[-1,999,0,1000,1,1001,99,1099,100,1100,101,1101]
```

Including, *but not limited to*, your example:

```
λ> sumsOfCombinations $ replicate 3 [1,11]
[[3],[13],[13],[23],[13],[23],[23],[33]]

λ> sumsOfCombinations $ replicate 4 [1,11]
[[4],[14],[14],[24],[14],[24],[24],[34],[14],[24],[24],[34],[24],[34],[34],[44]]
```

Here is its type:

```
λ> :t sumsOfCombinations
sumsOfCombinations :: (Num b, Foldable t) => t [b] -> [[b]]
```

As written, `sumsOfCombinations` gives you the exact output you are looking for. However, I don't think it is necessary to return a list of lists, so I would choose:

```
λ> let sumsOfCombinations' xs = sum <$> foldr (liftA2 (:)) [[]] xs

λ> :t sumsOfCombinations'
sumsOfCombinations' :: (Num b, Foldable t) => t [b] -> [b]

λ> sumsOfCombinations' $ replicate 3 [1,11]
[3,13,13,23,13,23,23,33]
```

Note that you can extract a helper from each of these to give you the combinations of elements from the lists:

```
λ> let combinations = foldr (liftA2 (:)) [[]]
λ> combinations [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
[[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,4,5],[2,4,6]]
```

So then you have:

```
sumsOfCombinations xs = (:[]) . sum <$> combinations xs
```

or, if you don't need to return a list of lists:

```
sumsOfCombinations' xs = sum <$> combinations xs
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, what you want is the Cartesian product of all the lists in a given list. Once you have that, then you can combine them in any way you like.

```
cartesian :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
cartesian [] = [[]]
cartesian (xs:xss) = [x : ys | x <- xs, ys <- cartesian xss]

mkSums :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
mkSums = map ((\x -> [x]) . sum) . cartesian
```